# How to iterate through XML values to make XML API call with iterative values?

Tags: python, xml, function, iterator, api-design

I am working on a project to extract data via this API (http://www.yourmembership.com/company/api-reference/). The API requires that the calls be made via XML. I have successfully been able to make calls and retrieve data back via HTTP response object using the 'requests' library in python.

My question is I want to develop a function that will iterate through IDs from one API call and plug them into another function which will make iterative API calls to get more data back about each ID.

For example the script I have now gives me a dump of all event IDs:

```
import requests

xml ="""

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<YourMembership>
   <Version>2.25</Version>
   <ApiKey></ApiKey>
   <CallID>008</CallID>
   <></>
   <SaPasscode></SaPasscode>
   <Call Method = "Sa.Events.All.GetIDs">
       <StartDate>2017/01/1</StartDate>
       <EndDate>2017/12/31</EndDate>
   </Call>
</YourMembership>
"""


headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
r = requests.post('https://api.yourmembership.com', data=xml,headers=headers)
print(r.text)
```

The response looks like this(no child objects)for 'print(r.text)':

```
<EventID>12345</EventID>
<EventID>67890</EventID>
<EventID>24680</EventID>
<EventID>13579</EventID>
<EventID>08642</EventID>
```

How can I take these event_IDs and iterate through the response object and plug them into this function below(function is not complete, rough draft) and get info for each event_ID by making iterative XML API calls by somehow plugging values for the  field ?

```
import requests
def xml_event_info():
xml ="""

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<YourMembership>
   <Version>2.25</Version>
   <ApiKey>xxx-xxx</ApiKey>
   <CallID>001</CallID>
   <></>
   <SaPasscode>xxxx</SaPasscode>
   <Call Method = "Sa.Events.Event.Get">
       <EventID>12345</EventID>
   </Call>
</YourMembership>
"""


headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
r = requests.post('https://api.yourmembership.com', data=xml,headers=headers)
print(r.text)
```

Thank you in advance, please let me know if my question does not make sense.

EDIT:

```
<YourMembership_Response>
<ErrCode>0</ErrCode>
<ExtendedErrorInfo></ExtendedErrorInfo>
<Sa.Events.All.GetIDs>
<EventID>98765</EventID>
</Sa.Events.All.GetIDs>
</YourMembership_Response>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider interfacing Python's built-in [etree](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) to parse the *YM_Response* and extract the *EventID* text as seen in example:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

txt="""
<YourMembership_Response>
    <ErrCode>0</ErrCode>
    <ExtendedErrorInfo></ExtendedErrorInfo>
    <Sa.Events.All.GetIDs>
        <EventID>98765</EventID>
    </Sa.Events.All.GetIDs>
</YourMembership_Response>
"""

dom = et.fromstring(txt)

for i in dom.iterfind('.//EventID'):    
    print(i.text)   
# 98765
```

Altogether, iteratively call your method passing Event IDs as a parameter that is then string formatted to XML string. See curly brace inside XML string and then `.format` in the `requests` line:

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

def xml_event_info(eventID):       
    xml ='''        
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <YourMembership>
       <Version>2.25</Version>
       <ApiKey>xxx-xxx</ApiKey>
       <CallID>001</CallID>
       <></>
       <SaPasscode>xxxx</SaPasscode>
       <Call Method = "Sa.Events.Event.Get">
           <EventID>{}</EventID>
       </Call>
    </YourMembership>        
    '''        
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    r = requests.post('https://api.yourmembership.com', 
                      data=xml.format(eventID), headers=headers)        
    print(r.text)      


xml ='''    
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<YourMembership>
   <Version>2.25</Version>
   <ApiKey>xxxxx</ApiKey>
   <CallID>008</CallID>
   <></>
   <SaPasscode>xxxx</SaPasscode>
   <Call Method = "Sa.Events.All.GetIDs">
       <StartDate>2017/01/1</StartDate>
       <EndDate>2017/12/31</EndDate>
   </Call>
</YourMembership>
'''        
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
r = requests.post('https://api.yourmembership.com', data=xml, headers=headers)

# BUILD XML TREE OBJECT    
dom = et.fromstring(r.text)

# PARSE EVENT ID TEXT AND PASS INTO FUNCTION
for i in dom.iterfind('.//EventID'):    
    xml_event_info(i.text)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response @Parfait. When you mention root do you mean something like this? see edit please

Comment: Yes. Is that the true response? If so, you can parse that with `etree`. And then what was the previous output?

Comment: Yes that is the true response, what do you mean by previous output? I am trying to run your code but no matter what I do to remove white spaces I keep getting error "ParseError: XML or text declaration not at start of entity: line 1, column 6"


error is not on line one its in the second part of the code block after the function in your last example.

Comment: I fixed the above issue by putting in the root elements into the code for '#BUILD XML TREE OBJECT'. After running your code how come when I print the 'dom' element it turns into '<Element 'YM_Response' at 0x11678dc10>'?

Comment: What I don't understand is the output after *The response looks like this(no child objects)for 'print(r.text)':*. My answer is predicated on this output. I would need to update solution to your update. Why did you post this list of `<EventID>` nodes?

Comment: I posted the list of <EventID> nodes because those are the IDs I want to be able to iterate through in another function to get the information about each of those IDs. And yes no child objects you are correct.

Comment: Got it. See edited answer. On your next question, always provide actual data and not snippets.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked perfectly. I am using this example to study and will post more actual data next time! thank you for the advice.